# High rtt value when using TURN server

Tags: webrtc, turn

Want to ask about high rtt value that I receive when I transferring media over TURN server. Everything works fine and rtt value is ok when I send media not via TURN server. I provided info that I found about rtt in webrtc-internals in both cases: when I use TURN server to send media and when I don't use it. [when I use TURN server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbIrU.png), [when I don't use TURN server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIrRJ.png).By the way my Turn server located in Canada. I heard that distance can influence for rtt. But I think that anyway when rtt over 300 it's too much. Want to hear any advises about that issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

TURN is relaying the data via that server in Canada so that is somewhat expected. In order to get a lower round-trip-time you will have to use a TURN server that is running closer to your users. See [this blog post](https://medium.com/the-making-of-appear-in/keep-your-turn-servers-close-8fff0a2a91f5) about the effect this has on average latency.

Comment: Do you think that 300 rtt is normal even when I connect to server in Canada?

Comment: that depends on where the server is hosted and where you are located. I get 200ms candidate gathering latency for a server in the US from Europe so 300ms for an actual call sounds reasonable

Comment: I also located in Europe